# Buffering an HTML content in the middle of other

Tags: php, html

I want to run a function after the content made( made by function ).
But I want that function to show html output before the content.

Like this:

```
<?php
//some html tags before
function showSideBarBeforeContent(){

}
//content
function showSideBarAfterContent(){

}
```

but I want to first show and process content after that showSideBarBeforeContent by the order but print out put by the shown order.

Need your suggestions.
Best Wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [ob-get-contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)
It does pretty much what you want.